# How do I host another website off a port of my ip?

Tags: html, web, server, ports

Basically, what I want to do with my site is I want to host another site off a port of my ip address. So like 192.168.0.1:8000. I host my website from a mac (using ampps), so is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by re-configuring apache virtualhosts here is a link https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html